# Looking for SAS coding to compute scores for a whole cohort based on scores calculated for a subgroup

Tags: sas

I am Looking for SAS coding to compute scores for a whole cohort based on scores calculated for a subgroup

I can create scores in the whole population by itself as my whole dataset but have no experience in using the fitted values of a subgroup dataset to compute scores for the whole population

I work with SAS coding

NA

Comment: Allow me to suggest you to kindly provide examples of what you have tried so far. A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Please review the guidelines on how to ask a question [ask]. It also helps if you can provide sample data and expected output (as text, not images) so if someone is trying to help via code they can ensure the code matches what you need.

Comment: Thank for your kind reply. I need to follow this order: 
“Estimate scores as an ‘‘unexposed-only’’ scores, from a regression model, fit only for the unexposed population, with the fitted values then should be computed for the entire cohort.”
I divided my cohort to exposed and unexposed groups and then created scores in my unexposed group:

Proc logistic data=unexposed descending;
Model outcome=age sex residency;
Output out=SS predicted=score;
Run;

I can calculate these scores in my exposed group separately by just replacing the dataset  but I have been asked to do something else

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!  If I understand your question, this will do what you want.

I grabbed some data from [sas support](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect053.htm):

```
  Data Neuralgia;
      input Treatment $ Sex $ Age Duration Pain $ @@;
      datalines;
   P  F  68   1  No   B  M  74  16  No  P  F  67  30  No
   P  M  66  26  Yes  B  F  67  28  No  B  F  77  16  No
   A  F  71  12  No   B  F  72  50  No  B  F  76   9  Yes
   A  M  71  17  Yes  A  F  63  27  No  A  F  69  18  Yes
   B  F  66  12  No   A  M  62  42  No  P  F  64   1  Yes
   A  F  64  17  No   P  M  74   4  No  A  F  72  25  No
   P  M  70   1  Yes  B  M  66  19  No  B  M  59  29  No
   A  F  64  30  No   A  M  70  28  No  A  M  69   1  No
   B  F  78   1  No   P  M  83   1  Yes B  F  69  42  No
   B  M  75  30  Yes  P  M  77  29  Yes P  F  79  20  Yes
   A  M  70  12  No   A  F  69  12  No  B  F  65  14  No
   B  M  70   1  No   B  M  67  23  No  A  M  76  25  Yes
   P  M  78  12  Yes  B  M  77   1  Yes B  F  69  24  No
   P  M  66   4  Yes  P  F  65  29  No  P  M  60  26  Yes
   A  M  78  15  Yes  B  M  75  21  Yes A  F  67  11  No
   P  F  72  27  No   P  F  70  13  Yes A  M  75   6  Yes
   B  F  65   7  No   P  F  68  27  Yes P  M  68  11  Yes
   P  M  67  17  Yes  B  M  70  22  No  A  M  65  15  No
   P  F  67   1  Yes  A  M  67  10  No  P  F  72  11  Yes
   A  F  74   1  No   B  M  80  21  Yes A  F  69   3  No
   ;
run;
```

Then subsetted down to build a model using only the males:

```
data males;
    set Neuralgia;
    where sex = "M";
run;
```

Then I built a model and saved the model details, into the work library, in a file called theMaleModel.

```
proc logistic data=males outmodel=work.theMaleModel;
    class Treatment;
    model Pain = Treatment Age Duration ;
run;
```

Then I apply the male model to the full dataset and save the scored results into a dataset, in the work library, called scoreEverybody:

```
proc logistic inmodel=work.theMaleModel;
   score data=Neuralgia out=scoreEverybody;
run;
```

You can see more examples like this if you look [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect073.htm).   If that answers your question please click the check next to this answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. I checked the SAS examples as you provided the link. I will try to use those functions tomorrow and hope it works